# Ways to do an interaction between two level 2 variables (IV and moderator) and a level 1 outcome?

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis

I recently was asked to help a colleague with some analyses thinking that we were looking at a cross-level interaction. When looking at the data it seems like the question being asked involves a Level-2 IV, a Level-2 moderator, and a level-1 DV. Can anyone point me to some good example syntax in either R or Mplus or any other resources to help with this? I've previously done cross-level interactions but for some reason my brain isn't reasoning this one through.

Relatedly, there is another question in there with a Level-3 IV, a Level-2 moderator, and a Level-1 DV. Similar to above, any guidance in the right direction would be appreciated?

Thanks, all.

Comment: It would probably help if you write down the equations. The way I read your first description is, there is an outcome $Y_1$ caused by the L2 variable $Z_1$. There is a L2 variable $Z_2$ and a L1 variable $Y_2$ that both moderate the effect of $Z_1$ on $Y_1$. Since you describe $Y_2$ as a dependent variable, I'm guessing it is caused by at least one variable, say $Q$. The equation for $Y_1$ is then: $Y_1 = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 Z_1 + \alpha_2 Z_1 Z_2 + \alpha_3 Z_1 Y_2 + \epsilon_1$. The equation for $Y_2$ is then: $Y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Q + \epsilon_2$. Is that somewhat close to what you mean?

Comment: Here I assumed linear models since you do not give any information about the distribution of the outcomes.

Comment: At least in lmer, it's really not that different from using level 2 predictors as main effects. Use the code you'd otherwise use and include your level2 * level2 interaction (or level2 * level3 interaction).

Comment: Hi folks. Thank you for the response and sorry for the delay in responding. To the point about the equations: I have only one outcome (Y1) that is level one with two level two predictors (Z1 and Z2) that interact. So my equation would be 1=0+11+22+312+1. Does this make sense? It does seem like I'd use standard lmer code. Given this set up should I be group or grand mean centering?

Answer (score 2):

The standard multilevel or mixed effects model can handle this problem, although it might not be wholly satisfying to your colleague. These models split the variance of the outcome into that which is within clusters and that which is between clusters. I prefer to show equations by these two groupings:

At level 1 (within cluster): $y_{ij} = \beta_{0j} + e_{ij},  e_{ij}\sim N(0, \sigma_e^2)$

and at level 2 (between cluster): $\beta_{0j} = \gamma_{00} + u_{0j}, u_{0j}\sim N(0, \sigma_u^2)$

In your colleague's case, their key IV and moderator are at the group level and only vary between clusters. Accordingly they are included in the between cluster portion of the model *and* can only explain between group variance in the outcome. They cannot explain within group variance because the predictors do not vary within groups.

The new between cluster equation would include the two main effect predictors $Z_{01j}$ and $Z_{02j}$ and their interaction $Z_{03j}$:

$\beta_{0j} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma  Z_{01j} + \gamma  Z_{02j} + \gamma  Z_{03j} +u_{0j}$

In mixed modeling software implementations, you typically just include all the predictors without having to worry about what level they sit at. Mplus is an exception, as you would want to declare the three $Z_j$ predictors in the BETWEEN statement under the variable command.